# styling drop down form element (selection) with CSS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, html, css

I have hunted around and have not found any methods to do what I would like. I would like to style the top level of a standard form drop down (selection) element.

I would like it to look like this:
[image]

Now I know I can style the border, text and graident with CSS but I am wondering if its easier to just make the drop down a static image?

Or is it even possible to style a drop down this way? I have never had any luck doing so.

EDIT: I found [this tutorial HERE](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/) that is pretty close. But just want to see others opinions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

Comment: I'm a big fan of this library http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ This is an example of how I used it in production, note the differences in how the <option>s render http://www.pfisterfaucets.com/Kitchen/Category/Kitchen-Faucets

Comment: thanks guys but neither of those are really styling it the way I was hoping. I found another link here which pretty well does what I need. http://danielneumann.com/blog/how-to-style-dropdown-with-css-only/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer here, this is exactly what I want to accomplish and it uses CSS only which is a bonus:
http://danielneumann.com/blog/how-to-style-dropdown-with-css-only/

```
select { 
font-size:1.1em; 
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: 200;
width:195px;
border:0; 
border-radius: 0px;
color:#787878; 
background:transparent;
padding-top: 7px; 
padding-bottom: 10px; 
-webkit-appearance: none;
*width:190px; 
*background:#58B14C;
}

#mainselection  { 
color: #787878 !important;
width: 197px;
background: url("http://i.imgur.com/N6SyH.png") no-repeat scroll 165px 8px, #f5f5f5; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: url('http://i.imgur.com/N6SyH.png') no-repeat scroll 169px 8px, -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%, #efefef 40%, #e8e8e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: url('http://i.imgur.com/N6SyH.png') no-repeat scroll 169px 8px, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f5f5f5), color-stop(40%,#efefef), color-stop(100%,#e8e8e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: url('http://i.imgur.com/N6SyH.png') no-repeat scroll 169px 8px, -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%,#efefef 40%,#e8e8e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: url('http://i.imgur.com/N6SyH.png') no-repeat scroll 169px 8px, -o-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%,#efefef 40%,#e8e8e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: url('http://i.imgur.com/N6SyH.png') no-repeat scroll 169px 8px, -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%,#efefef 40%,#e8e8e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: url('http://i.imgur.com/N6SyH.png') no-repeat scroll 169px 8px, linear-gradient(to bottom, #f5f5f5 0%,#efefef 40%,#e8e8e8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f5f5f5', endColorstr='#e8e8e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
border: solid 1px #D1D1D1;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #FFF;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #FFF;
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #FFF;
}
```

​
[Here is a live jsfiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/mattmagi/yvgZP/).

Thanks!

Comment: be aware the css3 styling is not available in some browsers

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Pryme8/prymeUI

I am working on developing a plugin that will allow for styling of all your elements to match themes like the select box you have created.

Its still in alpha development but Im working on it in my free time and as soon as I have support for at least 80% of DOM elements and their properties I will start adding theme's which hopefully with one call of a jquery string you will be able to style whole forms or pages without even having to worry about the CSS...